# Tag Prometheus alerts with labels

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I want to create PrometheusRule which generates alerts for "pod restarts" only for namespaces that are tagged with a specific label. How can I do that?

For e.g. if I mark
`k label namespace kube-system team=testing`

Then I am trying

```
        - alert: PodRestartsAlert 
          expr: (sum(increase(kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total{team="testing"}[5m])) by (namespace,pod)) >= 1
          annotations:
            description: "The pod {{ $labels.pod }} in namespace {{ $labels.namespace }} has experienced more than 1 restarts."
```

EDIT: I read about `kube-state-metrics` and `kube_namespace_labels` could help here. Can anyone please help me rewrite the above expression using  `kube_namespace_labels`. I tried this version but it seems to be incorrect:

```
expr: sum by (namespace, pod) (increase(kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total[5m])) * on(namespace) group_left() max(kube_namespace_labels{workload_servicenow_com_team="snowsk8s-fabric"}) >= 1
```

I also want to know about how I can use same label as part of annotations or labels in the alert rule.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you are asking? Because "only for namespaces that are tagged with a specific label" and "label this alert with namespace labels" are kind opposite ideas. Former one I believe is already solved, even here on SO a couple times: you need to "join" something like `kube_namespace_labels` and filter on it. And latter one is non trivial, as I understand it.

Comment: I got to know about kube_state_metrics after posting this question, editing my question based on that learning.